# Spark Dataset with Subselect in Where Condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I try to recreate a SQL query in Spark SQL. Normally i would insert into a table like this:

```
INSERT INTO Table_B 
( 
    primary_key,
    value_1,
    value_2
) 
SELECT DISTINCT
    primary_key,
    value_1,
    value_2
FROM 
    Table_A
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1 FROM 
Table_B
WHERE
Table_B.primary_key = Table_A.primary_key
);
```

Spark SQL is straightforward and I can load data from a TempView in a new dataset. Unfortunately i don't know how to reconstruct the where clause.

```
Dataset<Row> Table_B = spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT primary_key, value_1, value_2 FROM Table_A").where("NOT EXISTS ... ???" );
```

Answer (score 2):

Queries with not exists in TSQL can be rewritten with left join with "where":

```
SELECT Table_A.* 
FROM Table_A Left Join Table_B on Table_B.primary_key = Table_A.primary_key
Where Table_B.primary_key is null
```

Maybe, similar approach can be used in Spark, with left join. For example, for dataframes, smthing like:

```
aDF.join(bDF,aDF("primary_key")===bDF("primary_key"),"left_outer").filter(isnull(col("other_b_not_nullable_column")))
```

Answer (score 1):

SparkSQL doesn't currently have EXISTS & IN. "[(Latest) Spark SQL / DataFrames and Datasets Guide / Supported Hive Features](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#supported-hive-features)"

EXISTS & IN can always be rewritten using JOIN or LEFT SEMI JOIN. "[Although Apache Spark SQL currently does not support IN or EXISTS subqueries, you can efficiently implement the semantics by rewriting queries to use LEFT SEMI JOIN.](https://documentation.progress.com/output/DataDirect/odbcsparksqlhelp/index.html#page/odbcspark/subqueries.html)" OR can always be rewritten using UNION. AND NOT can be rewritten using EXCEPT.